# Popup keyboard in java

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, popup

for a embedded kiosk system i need a popup keyboard, something like in every android smartphone. If someone click on a textfield a popup keyboard will show, if someone click a other point as the textfield, the popupkeyboard will hide. 
I already realize the popupkeyboard:

```
public Keyboard() {
        super("pop-up keyboard");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        txt = new JTextField(20);
        keyboard = new PopUpKeyboard(txt);

        txt.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = txt.getLocationOnScreen();
                p.y += 30;
                keyboard.setLocation(p);
                keyboard.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

If i click on the textfield the keyboard open. But now i have no idea how to hide the keyboard if the focus on the textfield is lost. I have tried this, but it haven't worked:

```
txt.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        //

    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        keyboard.setVisible(false);
    }

    });
```

Have someone a idea how to hide the keyboard?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also understand what's wrong in your code and can suggest an aswer for you question. Please also look [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347001/prevent-jpopupmenu-from-closing-when-alt-is-pressed/). Probably it helps you to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I already realize the popupkeyboard:

The popup keyboard should be an undecorated JDialog. Focus would be on the dialog while you are pressing keys.

> if someone click a other point as the textfield, the popupkeyboard will hide.

Then you can add a `WindowListener` to the dialog and handle the `windowDeactivated` event and close the dialog.